# How to show image(dynamic) in android dialog?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-dialog

I am creating gallery in android where I can put the images using recyclerview which is working fine. Now my requirement is when I click on the particular image it should open in dialog . For now I have hard-coded the images in drawable but it will come from API as a url . This is what I am doing :
Here is the java code

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        //viewHolder.title.setText(galleryList.get(i).getImageTitle());
        viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        viewHolder.img.setImageResource((galleryList.get(i).getImageId()));
        //Picasso.with(context).load(galleryList.get(i).getImageId()).resize(240, 120).into(viewHolder.img);
        viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog nagDialog = new Dialog(context);
                nagDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                nagDialog.setCancelable(false);
                nagDialog.setContentView(R.layout.image_preview);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView)nagDialog.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img1);
                nagDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my layout file which is getting opened over the dialog (image_preview.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/image_preview"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The adapter class :

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.traveloholic.R;
import com.traveloholic.models.Gallery;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Gallery> galleryList;
    private Context context;

    public GalleryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Gallery> galleryList) {
        this.galleryList = galleryList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_cell_layout, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final GalleryAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

        //viewHolder.title.setText(galleryList.get(i).getImageTitle());
        viewHolder.img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        viewHolder.img.setImageResource((galleryList.get(i).getImageId()));
        //Picasso.with(context).load(galleryList.get(i).getImageId()).resize(240, 120).into(viewHolder.img);
        viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog nagDialog = new Dialog(context);
                nagDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                nagDialog.setCancelable(true);
                nagDialog.setContentView(R.layout.image_preview);
                Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.img1).into((ImageView) nagDialog.findViewById(R.id.image_preview)) ;
                nagDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return galleryList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        private TextView title;
        private ImageView img;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            //title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        }
    }

}
```

Right now I need to hard code the set ImageResource value from drawable(the images will come from API) whereas I want whenever I click the image that particular image should be open in dialog . I tried to google but only find the same solution i.e to hardcode the value from drawable. How can I do that ??

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you already have an `ArrayList` called **galleryList**, you can get the URL from this `ArrayList` as follows :

`onBindViewHolder` gives you the position ***i*** of the photo, so this line will give you the url by position :

```
galleryList.get(i).getURL()
```

`getURL()` maybe not exist in your Gallery class, since you didn't post your Gallery model class

```
viewHolder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final Dialog nagDialog = new Dialog(context);
                nagDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                nagDialog.setCancelable(false);
                nagDialog.setContentView(R.layout.image_preview);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView)nagDialog.findViewById(R.id.image_preview);

                Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(galleryList.get(i).getURL()) <-----
                .into(imageView);

                nagDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks , But is there any method available in View class which can give the URL when I click on any image ?

Comment: @NeerajN Sorry but I didn't understand your question properly, give me more details, I will gladly help you if I can

Comment: I will show all the images in Recycler View, but how do I get the clicked Image URL which needs to be load in the picasso/glide?? Will the View class object contain the clicked image URL ??

Comment: @NeerajN,Since you have the list of images, then you already have an array of the URLs, you can create an Interface with onClick method, call this method in your adapter class, and implement the interface in your Activity, or just post your Adapter class, I will help you

Comment: Sure , I have edited my question . Please find the adapter class there.

Comment: @NeerajN, I've updated my answer, hope this will help you